# How to delete each row in php while loop using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following php code :

```
<tr class="delete_ex_ph_label_data">              
    <td align="left">
        <select name="phone_label_ex[]" class="select2 work_phone_class">
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            <?php
            $get_orderby =  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT order_type FROM contact_label_type");
            $get_orderby_re =  mysqli_fetch_array($get_orderby);
            $ph_orderby = $get_orderby_re['order_type'];
            $get_label_type =  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM contact_label_type WHERE clid = '1' ORDER BY order_type $ph_orderby"); 

            while($get_label_type_re =  mysqli_fetch_array($get_label_type)){
            $label_type_id = (int) $get_label_type_re['ctid'];
            $label_type = inputvalid($get_label_type_re['contact_label_type']);

            if($ctid_d_cl == $label_type_id){
            $sel = 'selected="selected"';
            }else{
            $sel = '';
            } 

            echo "<option value=' $label_type_id' $sel> $label_type</option>";  
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td align="right">                
        <input type="text" name="phone_label_value_ex[]" class="small3 work_phone_class" id="work_phone" placeholder="phone"value="<?php echo $data_cl; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ctid" value="<?php echo $ctid_d_cl; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="label_id" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="phone_label_cdid_ex[]" value="<?php echo $cdid_d_cl; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="phone_mid[]" value="<?php echo $id_d_cl; ?>">
        <spam class="delete_ex_ph_label"><a href='#'>&nbsp;X</a></spam>
    </td>              
</tr>
```

**Which showing bellow image :**

[image]

**Now when I click (+) sign it showing (X) sign to each row, Like bellow image :**

[image]

**Now I want to remove/hide each row by clicking on (X) sign. So that I am using following jquery code :**

```
$(".delete_ex_ph_label", $(this)).on('click', function() {         
   $(".delete_ex_ph_label_data", $(this)).remove();
});
```

**But it's not removing, How can I remove each row by clicking on (X) sign ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter in the $() function is for context (scoping). http://api.jquery.com/jquery/

In your event handler, $(this) refers to the clicked X, which does not contain the element with the class '.delete_ex_ph_label_data'.  Instead, modify your event handler to go up the ancestor chain to the first '.delete_ex_ph_label_data' and delete that.

```
$(".delete_ex_ph_label").on('click', function() {         
   $(this).parents('.delete_ex_ph_label_data').remove();
});
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6aev2vtb/)